# Least and greatest value of $|z|$ given that $|z- 4/z| = 2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If the complex number $z$ satisfies the equation $\left\lvert z- {4\over z}\right\rvert = 2$ then the least and the greatest values of $|z|$ are ?

***My try***
 $\left\lvert z- {4\over z}\right\rvert = 2$

$\left| |z| - \left\lvert z- {4\over z}\right\rvert \right| \le 2$.

Comment: See http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml

Comment: How do you define $\mathrm{mod}(z)?$

Comment: mod(z) is defined as $\sqrt( x^2+y^2)$ if Z= x+iy

Comment: @ labbhattacharjee i have seen it and know the inequalities but cannot understand how to proceed further

Comment: Divide by $2$ and let $w = \frac{z}{2}$. The equation becomes $\lvert w - 1/w\rvert = 1$. Square it, you get (after a little rearranging) a quadratic equation in $x = \lvert w\rvert^2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given $$\left|z-\frac{4}{z}\right| = 2$$ and here we have to find $\max$ and $\min$ of $|z|$

So $$|z| = \left|\left(z-\frac{4}{z}\right)+\frac{4}{z}\right|\leq \left|z-\frac{4}{z}\right|+\frac{4}{|z|}$$

Above we have used $\bf{\triangle \; Inequality}$

So $$|z|\leq 2+\frac{4}{|z|}\Rightarrow |z|^2-2|z|\leq 4$$

So $$\left(|z|-1\right)^2 \leq 5$$

Now after that You can solve it.

Comment: Hey. (excuse me for no mathjax. I will update this). If you consider the identity |z1(+-)z2| <= |z1| + |z2|, where z1=z and z2=4/z, then wont the inequality become 2<= |z|+|4/z|, which is totally the different thing?

Answer (score 6):

If you know $\left|\frac zw\right|=\frac{|z|}{|w|}$, then you can solve your inequality for real $|z|$.  Then see if real $z$ attains those max and min.
$$|r-4/r|\leq2\\-2r\leq r^2-4\leq2r\\5\leq(r+1)^2,(r-1)^2\leq5\\-1+\sqrt{5}\leq r\leq1+\sqrt{5}$$

Comment: But how is this helpful??